# Error running Parse Server locally

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I followed https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server to install Parse server on MacOS locally :

```
    $ npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
    $ mongodb-runner start
    $ parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test
```

However, when I execute "mongodb-runner start", I got this error stack trace:

```
Starting a MongoDB deployment to test against...ERR! Error retrieving Error: socket hang up

    ERR! Error retrieving     at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:250:15)
    ERR! Error retrieving     at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:342:23)
    ERR! Error retrieving     at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
    ERR! Error retrieving     at Socket.emit (events.js:179:7)
    ERR! Error retrieving     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    ERR! Error retrieving     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    ERR! Error retrieving     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    ERR! Error retrieving  http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/src/ : { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
    ERR! Error: socket hang up undefined undefined
    { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Any advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear MongoDB download cache. On Windows, it's in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.mongodb\versions\downloads`. then re-run the command again.